# Create-React-App production overwrites css

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, build, production

Running `npm run build` outputs a diffrent css compiled website than when running `npm start` what's the difference and why does it happen? The posts i found were about changing `webpack.config` but i know that `create-react-app work` a bit differently. May you shine some light?

My `app.js` :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {store, persistor} from './Reducers/configStore'
import {PersistGate} from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

import './index.css';
import './App.css';
import "normalize.css";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import "@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css";
import "@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css";
import 'react-notifications-component/dist/theme.css';

require('dotenv').config();

const Piazeta = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
                <App />
            </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Piazeta />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Can ou share your code please ?

Comment: which part? i don't really know where this problem could start from

Comment: I think CSS files (yours and the one who overwrite) and `app.js` are enough

Comment: i don't really know which file overwrites the one written by me, most of the css is just the same but some paddings, some margins are just awefully wrong, like there isn't even any rule to it. here's the index.js https://codeshare.io/5wLNMJ the App is just a container for other components

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in the development build the bootstrap css was overwriting the css written by me and in the production build it was the other way around. I had a couple of things named the same which made the problems appear. Double check your css every time i guess, the order of them differs in prod and build